I have an Issue with event DropDown in combobox in Access's form
In a form, I have a combo box that changes dynamically, i.e., during execution each time I select it. Everything works fine except for the DropDown, which does not "auto-expand." I am sending the code I am using.
Thanks in advance.
Option Compare Database

Dim Seleccion As Integer

Const MarcaSQL1 As String = "SELECT pres_marca.Marca FROM pres_marca;"
Const MarcaSQL2 As String = "SELECT pres_modelo.Descripcion FROM pres_modelo WHERE (((pres_modelo.marca)=[textomarca]));"
Const MarcaSQL3 As String = "SELECT pres_cisterna.descripcion, pres_cisterna.Marca FROM pres_cisterna WHERE (((pres_cisterna.Marca) = [Textomarca])) ORDER BY pres_cisterna.Cisterna;"


Private Sub Form_Current()
    Seleccion = 1
    Caracteristicas.RowSource = MarcaSQL1
    Caracteristicas.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub Caracteristicas_AfterUpdate()
    
    If Seleccion = 1 Then
        Textomarca = Caracteristicas
        Seleccion = 2
        Caracteristicas.RowSource = MarcaSQL2
        Caracteristicas.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
        Caracteristicas.Dropdown
    
    ElseIf Seleccion = 2 Then
        Textomodelo = Caracteristicas
        Seleccion = 3
        Caracteristicas.RowSource = MarcaSQL3
        Caracteristicas.Requery
        Caracteristicas.Dropdown
    
    ElseIf Seleccion = 3 Then
        TextoCisterna = Caracteristicas
        Seleccion = 1
        Caracteristicas.RowSource = MarcaSQL1
        Caracteristicas.Requery
        Caracteristicas.Dropdown
    
    End If
    
End Sub


Why would you use combobox AfterUpdate event to set RowSource and expand itself? Use GotFocus. Why would you need to set RowSourceType?

hi @June7. Setting the RowSourceType was just for testing purposes since it didn't expand automatically. As for the RowSource, it's to avoid having two or more comboboxes where the data in each one is conditioned or filtered by the previous ones

I have tried like this but it doesn't do the dropdown either
`If Seleccion = 1 Then
    Textomarca = Caracteristicas
    Caracteristicas = Textomarca
    Seleccion = 2
    Caracteristicas.RowSource = MarcaSQL2
    Caracteristicas.Requery
    Caracteristicas.SetFocus
    DoCmd.GoToControl "Caracteristicas"
    Caracteristicas.Dropdown
ElseIf Seleccion = 2 Then
    Textomodelo = Caracteristicas
    Seleccion = 3
    Caracteristicas.RowSource = MarcaSQL3
    Caracteristicas.SetFocus

... `

I did a test with AfterUpdate and stepped through code. I can see the dropdown box appear but it is empty. It disappears when event completes. Can't do what you want.

Correction, I see blank dropdown when selecting item with mouse click. If I type in box and press Enter or Tab I get a populated dropdown. Again, it doesn't stay.

Can I send the file or a link with a shared folder and the complete example here? I don't know if is correct to do this in the forum

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Cannot attach files. Can provide link to a fileshare but it is not appreciated. SO protocol is all information to analyze issue should be included in question, not download files. There are forums that allow attaching files to post. However, providing your file won't alter my comment. Can't use AfterUpdate as you have attempted.
